# Lower bounds on max-flow and assignment problems

Tags: complexity-theory, network-flow, lower-bounds, assignment-problem

As far as I know, all existing [strongly polynomial algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Strongly_and_weakly_polynomial_time) for flows and assignment problem have $\Omega(V^3)$ complexity [in the arithmetic model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_circuit_complexity) (assuming the graph is dense).  I'm interested in the arithmetic model of computation, where each arithmetic operation on two numbers takes $O(1)$ time regardless of the size of the numbers, not the RAM model.

Is there any theoretical result or conjecture that explains this? I know that there are conjectured complexity lower bounds for problems in **P** based on 3SUM/APSP/some other problems, but I've never seen them applied to flow-related problems.